# Don't find /var/lib/postgresql/data/ directory on ubuntu when created docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I found the following mentioned at many places -

```
docker run -d \
    --name some-postgres \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword \
    -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata \
    -v /custom/mount:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    postgres
```

My only question is that I am unable to find `/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata` directory itself. I don't see any `postgresql` directory under `/var/lib`. Why is it? And just wonder how does it work if there is no directory?

Comment: For one who voted negative on it, the following command could have helped instead `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash`. I wasn't sure that it goes inside the container just like the directories outside it.

Answer (score 1):

The `-v` in your command mounts `/custom/mount` on your *host* (the machine where you run `docker` command) to *container's* `/var/lib/postgresql/data`. So the `pgdata` you are looking for is on *host's* `/custom/mount/pgdata`.

Of course, `/custom/data` is only an example name, you have to replace it with your real directory.

Comment: If I don't mount, where can I find `/var/lib/postgresql/data` ?

Comment: I have the same question, too

Comment: @infinite i have the same question: when not mounted, where can i find /var/lib/postgresql/data? did you find it?

Comment: If you don't mount a directory from your host machine, then the directory exists only inside the container. When you recreate the container, all data is lost, unless you mounted a persistent disk

Comment: @VesaKarjalainen yes i definitely understood the part you mentioned above but i'm trying to symlink /var/lib/postgresql/data to a location inside my codebase (which is persisted). The issue is i can't locate /var/lib/postgresql/data :(

Comment: @Mathieu I don't recall it mate but guess I had an answer. I will try to look into it again.